# What is "spill" in the context of Nashorn ScriptObjects?

Tags: nashorn

I'm profiling some of our Nashorn code. We pool and re-use our ScriptContexts between executions. I've noticed the ScriptContext is leaking memory somewhere, and I can trace it back to the `spill` attribute in the `Global` class:

[image: Profile of spill object]

What does the spill do? Is there any way to clear it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add properties to an object after it is created like "obj.x = 34" after "obj" is created and initialized, Nashorn creates "spill" area or expands already created "spill" area to hold these additional properties. If you initialize all properties at the constructor (or in an object literal), then there won't be any "spill" area in that object. Global is inherently "expanding" object forever - as you eval more code you keep creating more variables. So, there would be a spill for global.

Comment: Btw, this part of code has changed in jdk8u60 (i.e., the way current ScriptContext is associated with Global object). Will you please try early access download of jdk8u60 ( https://jdk8.java.net/download.html )?  If the "bug" / "suspect leak" still persists, please write to nashorn-dev alias and/or file a bug.